# How to alter the color of an HTML link when hovering over a list?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

In my HTML5 code I am using lists to create tabs in my navigation bar.

```
<div id="nav_tabs">
 <ul>
  <a href="Index_V2.html"> 
   <li>
   Home
   </li>
  </a>
  <a href="#media"> 
   <li>
   Media
   </li>
  </a>
  <a href="#agenda"> 
   <li>
   Agenda
   </li>
  </a>
 </ul>
</div>
```

When the user hovers over one of those tabs the background color and text color changes. However, for my Media tab in my list I added a drop-down menu. The HTML for that is:

```
<a href="#media"> 
<li>
 Media
 <ul class="submenu">
  <a href="media_music.html"><li>Music</li></a>
  <a href="media_photo.html"><li>Photo</li></a>
  <a href="media_video.html"><li>Video</li></a>
  <a href="media_band.html"><li>Band</li></a>
  <a href="media_interview.html"><li>Interviews</li></a>
  <a href="media_archive.html"><li>Archive</li></a>
 </ul>
</li>
```

The drop down menu works and the Media tab background color changes to white on hover as it is supposed to. Unfortunately, the "Media" text in the tab remains its original color.

This is the CSS that handles the change of color etc:

```
nav {
width: auto;
text-transform: uppercase;
background: #ff4e00;
height: 50px;
}
nav a {
color: white;
}
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
height: 35px;
margin: 0px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 26px;
-webkit-transition: .2s linear;
-moz-transition: .2s linear;
-o-transition: .2s linear;
-webkit-transition: .2s linear;
-moz-transition: .2s linear;
-o-transition: .2s linear;
}
#nav_tabs ul li:hover {
background: white;
color: #ff4e00;
}
.submenu {
position: relative;
width: 10px;
top: 17px;
right: 15px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
display: none;
background: black;
}
.submenu li {
background: #ff4e00;
width: 150px;
}
li:hover .submenu {
display: block;
}
```

I am trying to get the "Media" link text to change to the same color as all the others, but since the Link/List order is different it obviously doesn't work the same. I have tried to use:

```
#nav_tabs ul a:hover {
    color: #ff4e00;
}
```

But this only changes the color of the text when the user hovers over the link/text. It does not change the color of the text when the user hovers over the tab which is what I am looking for.

I managed to recreate my issue [here in JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ofapac/1/edit). When the user hovers over the "Media" tab, the background of the tab changes but the text-color does not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! not really clear what you try to acheive...
Try to make a example code in fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/S6cgk/

Comment: Thanks, edited the question and added a link to a JSBin where I managed to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is this:

Instead of:

```
#nav_tabs ul a:hover {
    color: #ff4e00;
}
```

Do this:

```
#nav_tabs ul:hover a {
    color: #ff4e00;
}
```

You can place the :hover on any element in the CSS selector chain, it doesn't have to go on the last one. This means that when you hover over a UL, all of the child anchor tags will get the styles.

But a longer answer is you have poorly formatted HTML. You have empty anchor tags floating in the `<ul>` tags by themselves, instead of wrapped in `<li>` elements. You've also got anchor tags wrapping `<li>` elements rather than inside of them.

This means your whole cascading relationship is going to be off. Here is the revised HTML (I removed some stuff for simplicity, I'll let you add it back in using this new structure as a guide):

```
<body>
  <nav id="nav_tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Index_V2.html">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#media">Media</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="media_music.html">Music</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

And then you should be able to adjust the CSS accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks! Managed to fix it with your explanation and learned some new tricks.

Answer (score 0):

As some one mentioned in the comments, your HTML is not valid,
valid chields of  are only

s  (you have to put the  inside them).
In your code when the browser parse it .. tags get replaced and your css dont match it.

Here is the edited code:  http://jsbin.com/ofapac/8/edit

```
<nav>
    <div id="nav_tabs">
        <ul> 
            <li>
                <a href="Index_V2.html">Home</a>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <a href="#media">Media</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="media_music.html">Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="media_photo.html">Photo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="media_video.html">Video</a></li>
                    <li><a href="media_band.html">Band</a></li>
                    <li><a href="media_interview.html">Interviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="media_archive.html">Archive</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <a>Agenda</a>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <a>Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And second thing,  tags does not inherit font settings from there parent tag, so you have to specified it explisidly. there are 2 extra rows on the bottom of the CSS.

```
nav ul li a{
  color: white;
}
nav ul li:hover > a{
    color: #ff4e00;
}
```